# crystal reports not displaying a result

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

I'm trying to connect a dataset to my report in VS 2010 with CR 13.1. Did this four years ago with an older version and now it's not behaving. I checked the content of the dataset after the query and it's got what I'm looking for so the getdata function is not an issue. I've tried using the report object and an empty report document to connect the dataset to the report. (CrystalReportSource is already hardwired to the report - and that's another issue.)

I've got a button on the form along with the viewer and source objects so I can try the alternate method. Neither method populates the report and I can't find any code anywhere that clarifies the issue.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private ds As New DataSe
    Private da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Private dsUORInfoT As New DataSet
    Private rptUOR As New CrystalReport
    Private UORrpt As New ReportDocument
    Private reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt")



    Private ConnectionString As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("dbName") = "VAPD"
        GetData("select * from t_offense where offense_nbr ='201305170216-3529'", dsUORInfoT)
        UORrpt.Load(reportPath)
        'rptUOR.SetDataSource(dsUORInfoT)
        UORrpt.SetDataSource(dsUORInfoT)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = UORrpt
        'CrystalReportSource1.Report.

    End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote a short guide on how to use Crystal in VS2010 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140260/updating-data-provider-of-crystal-reports/17244380#17244380 this should help

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit of a mess. I guess I neglected to mention that I'm using an Oracle database. What does this mean? It means that support for the dataset object is mediocre, at best. I had created a multiple table dataset with the expectation that things would behave as advertised. It turns out that .FILL for the dataset object includes the ability to name a table, and for SQLServer it will fill the appropriate table. For Oracle, not so much.

So the code as displayed does work, to a degree, but I hadn't filled all of the tables in the dataset so it wasn't going to work anyway and when I tried to fill them that didn't work.

I've since switched to a view based model where I'm using views structured to provide the required data to the report. This eliminates the need for a multiple table dataset, which would probably have been either cooler or more efficient, but in point of fact doesn't really work.