# (VB / ACCESS / CR) Filter VB Crystal Report based on Access Form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

Before I get to the question, here is an overview of what is going on.

#### Access

A form that has a ComboBox that selects a JobId

#### Crystal Reports

A Report that calls info from several tables, all based on the JobID

#### VB

A Form (Using the Crystal Reports Plug-In) that shows the Report outside of the Crystal Reports Designer app.

### My Problem

I need the report displayed in VB to be filtered to the job chosen in the Access ComboBox.

#### Update

I have my Database linked to VS2012, and that works fine without any issues. I can pull info from a Table easily. What I need to do is link the ComboBox *from* an **Access Form** *to* **VS2012** to filter the Report.

I hope that makes my question clearer.

#### Update 2

I was able to figure out how to create a *SELECT* Query based on the value of my ComboBox inside of Access, so I should be able to use that to access the Value I am looking for, however I still need to know how to use that value as a filter for CR...

Comment: If you haven't got this setup yet, here is a guide I wrote to do just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140260/updating-data-provider-of-crystal-reports/17244380#17244380

Comment: Looking over that link, it seems like it is close to what I want, but I have a few questions. 1) In VS2012, I do not see a way to start a .Net app, just VB, C#, and a few others. 2) After I get that all started, I still don't see how to link a Field from a Form in Access to VB.

Comment: .net refers to the framework which is manipulated using a .net languge such as VB.net or C#. So when I say .net app you can create one in VS using any of the .net languages such as C# or VB.net. As for how you select a record in an Access combobox, which then filters a CR in a VB.net app, that's a bit more complicated. Is there a reason you don't have the combobox on a VB.net form? I guess you could edit a datatable in your access database from Access, which is then used as the recordsource for your .net CR.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create a saved Select Query in Access that replicates the query in CR, and name that query [JobReport_base]. Then, create another saved Select Query in Access and name it [JobReport_current]. Add some code to your Access form that updates the `.SQL` property of the [JobReport_current] query to return just the records for the selected [JobId], something like

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("JobReport_current")
qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM JobReport_base WHERE JobId = " & cbxJobId
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Then update your Crystal Report to pull the data from the [JobReport_current] query instead of the individual tables.

Comment: I like where this is going, however, the reason I am using CR in the first place is because the Query I need for the report is too complex for Access, otherwise i'd just use the built-in tools.

Comment: If the query is too complex for Access you can try to reduce its complexity. Try reducing the size of your aliases or getting rid of them altogether. Try to reduce the amount of text in all the queries that work together to produce your final query. There are a bunch of options here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103429

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions. In your case, the simplest ones are the following:

- There is this 'sqlQueryString' property of the report that you could update by directly updating the string.
- You could also add a parameter (let's call it 'PAR_yourCombobox') to the report. When accessing the report in your VB code, just set the value of your parameter to the value on the screen. as far as I remember, it should look like:

  yourReport.parameterFields(i).addCurrentValue yourForm.controls("yourCombobox").value

Comment: While I have some experience in VBA, I am very limited in VB, can you expound a little more? I need to take the ComboBox from form frmHub2 called, say, cmbSelector, and move that value, during runtime, onto my VB form.

Comment: then the value you need is forms("frmHub2").controls("cmbSelector").value (or forms("frmHub2").controls("cmbSelector").text)